# AuthType not allowed here

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My .htaccess file was working last year, and as far as I know I had not changed it. However, I am now getting the following error:

```
AuthType not allowed here
```

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /pwd/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

In case it helps my main apache .conf file for this domain looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  ServerName subdomain.example.com

  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/sites/example.com/subdomain

  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog /var/sites/example.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/sites/example.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 5):

`AuthType` (and other directives) not being allowed "here" is almost certainly a missing `AllowOverride` allowing `.htaccess` files to override the directive(s).

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride

`AllowOverride` only goes in `<Directory>` sections.  The solution might look something like this:

```
<Directory "/var/sites/example.com/subdomain">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

which would allow `.htaccess` overrides only in the `/var/sites/example.com/subdomain` directory.

A `<Directory>` directive will already exist and you may wish to modify it rather than add a new one.  This search help locate it on most Linux systems:

```
grep -r "Directory" /etc/httpd/
```

Comment: This works just fine but you could also use `Authconfig`that seems more secure than `All`. I've submitted a review.

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier Noted that you can be more specific with AllowOverride.

Comment: The httpd service also ned to be restarted for the change to take effect. `systemctl restart httpd` ;)

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier That is true about the restart (ideally, do a "graceful" restart: `apachectl -k graceful` or `httpd -k graceful`). Your `systemctl` example would not work on my system(s). :-)